# Comando SELECT no MYSQL está duplicando um resultado (que não está duplicado no banco de dados)

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo um select simples para retornar uma tabela no Excel, porém, quando executo o comando, algumas linhas estão sendo duplicadas no resultado. Segue o código abaixo:

```sql
SELECT
    distinct movimentacao.DATA, movimentacao.COD, CADASTRO_MP.DESCRICAO, CADASTRO_MP.GRUPO, CADASTRO_MP.SUBGRUPO, movimentacao.QUANTIDADE, cadastro_mp.UNIDADE, movimentacao.ENTRADA_SAIDA, movimentacao.ALMOXARIFADO, CADASTRO_MP.ULTIMO_PRECO, CADASTRO_MP.ULTIMO_PRECO * movimentacao.QUANTIDADE  
FROM movimentacao
LEFT JOIN CADASTRO_MP 
    ON CADASTRO_MP.COD = MOVIMENTACAO.COD 
ORDER BY movimentacao.DATA;
```

Alguém sabe dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Já busquei em algumas perguntas aqui no stackoverflow porém não consegui solucionar meu problema.

Comment: Usa um `GROUP BY` que resolve.

Comment: Tente adicionar um exemplo de dado que aparece duplicado. Para isso acontecer, o problema está no relacionamento/dados das tabelas.

Comment: Quantos registros com o COD que duplica tem na tabela CADASTRO_MP?

Comment: Como você está utilizando a cláusula DISTINCT não deve haver registros duplicados no resultado. Talvez você tenha a impressão de que as linhas são duplicadas mas efetivamente não são. Por ex. um campo texto com um espaço a mais torna o campo diferente.

Comment: DISTINCT não funciona quando você seleciona mais de uma coluna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
SELECT distinct movimentacao.ID, movimentacao.DATA, movimentacao.COD, 
CADASTRO_MP.DESCRICAO, CADASTRO_MP.GRUPO,
CADASTRO_MP.SUBGRUPO, movimentacao.QUANTIDADE, 
cadastro_mp.UNIDADE, movimentacao.ENTRADA_SAIDA, 
movimentacao.ALMOXARIFADO, CADASTRO_MP.ULTIMO_PRECO, 
CADASTRO_MP.ULTIMO_PRECO * movimentacao.QUANTIDADE  
FROM movimentacao left JOIN CADASTRO_MP 
ON CADASTRO_MP.COD = MOVIMENTACAO.COD 
GROUP BY movimentacao.ID
ORDER BY movimentacao.DATA
```

Comment: Desta forma não funciona pois o CADASTRO_MP.COD pode se repetir, porém com a data diferente... Utilizando o GROUP_BY ele mostra apenas um registro de cada .COD

Comment: Consegui! Tive que buscar o ID(que é primary key) da tabela MOVIMENTACAO_ALMOX e agrupar por ele. Obrigado!